# Management Studio default file save location

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Open a new query window.  Write some SQL.  Save the script, the Save File As
dialog box opens - but always to the same default location in the Profiles
directory.  Is there any way to set my default file location?  ...Like I used
to do with apps from the 1980s?

Under Tools|Options a default location can be specified for query results.
I need the same thing for new queries (the text editor).  Tried changing
locations in the Registry but SSMS just overwrote my changes.  Any
suggestions?

(I saw this unanswered question at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30098335/management-studio-default.aspx
 and I had same exact question so I just reposted it here)

Comment: in SSMS 2012 the default save location for query results is also used for saving SQL Scripts

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I found a link expaining how to do this properly, at least for SQL 2005. Think it will work for later versions as well.

[Changing the my projects folder](https://web.archive.org/web/20110829003107/http://visualstudiohacks.com/options/changing-the-my-projects-folder-location-and-other-settings-in-ssms//)

> The settings are stored in an `.vssettings` XML file in `My Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Settings` folder. Make sure you close SSMS
> before making changes to this file: SSMS writes to it when you close
> the application and will overwrite any changes you make. To change the
> `My Projects` folder, you are looking for this line:

```
   <PropertyValue name="ProjectsLocation">%vsspv_user_documents%\My
   Projects</PropertyValue>
```

> The value inside is the location of the `My Projects` folder. Simply
> change the value, and the next time you open SSMS the `My Projects`
> folder will be mapped.

Comment: Note: When trying this out, when I click Save, I still get the original default project folder. But clicking on the 'My Projects' button on the left panel of the save dialog brings me to the folder where I want my scripts saved. Thanks.

Answer (score 80):

This is 5 years old now, but it doesn't mention SSMS version, so I thought I'd add an update for SSMS 2012 and SSMS 2014. Step one differs between the versions, and then the rest is the same:

**SSMS 2012**

1. Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application

**SSMS 2014**

1. Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application

**SSMS 2016**

1. Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application

**SSMS 17**

1. Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application

**SSMS 18**

1. Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Application

**All (continued)**

2. Open ssms.application.pkgdef with text editor(e.g. Notepad)
3. Change the value of DefaultProjectsLocation
   "DefaultProjectsLocation"="$MyDocuments$\SQL Server Management Studio"
4. For query storage location (query itself, not results), edit this:
   "DefaultUserFilesFolderRoot"="SQL Server Management Studio"
5. Save the file

Thanks to this source: http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php/How_to_change_the_default_query_save_location_in_SSMS/?TopicId=41425&Posts=0

Comment: I am on SSMS 2012, so none of the other "answers" worked.  Thanks :)

Comment: This was the only non-workaround solution for SSMS 2014 as well.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me in SSMS 2016 Release Candidate. But, this only solves the problem of where Save As defaults to save new queries. It does not solve the (unasked) question of where File Open looks for existing files...

Comment: Thanks D-Money That also worked with SQL management studio 2016

Comment: Sql 2016 location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application

Comment: @DavidFawzy that should be 130 for SSMS 2016, not 120.

Comment: If your version isn't listed here, you probably just need to look through all the folders 120, 130, etc, starting at the highest number and work your way down, until you find the ssms.application.pkgdef file..  Look in \140, then \130, then \120.. etc, etc.

Comment: If you could add the instructions from David Guerra for SSMS 18 this would be perfect. I've come here once or twice since I upgraded and couldn't figure out the latest version.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. And Microsoft should just include that setting in the UI.

Answer (score 9):

A simple work around is to create a shortcut to your desired save location.  Place the shortcut in the SSMS\Projects directory.   When saving, select "All Files (*.*)" at the bottom, then double click your shortcut.

Not ideal, but a quick and simple work around.

Answer (score 6):

Just to make sure, did you update the locations in the registry here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\General\ProjectLocationEntries
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this for a long time too!

Comment: Studio resets the values of those reg items when I reopen it.

Comment: Yes I have now seen this as well (settings overwritten on restart) I'll look into it.

Answer (score 6):

The installation location for **SSMS 18 / 19** has changed, along with the location of the configuration file that controls the default file save location.

1. Close all running instances of SSMS.
2. Locate your SSMS installation folder.  By default it is:

- **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio XX**

3. Within that folder, go to: **Common7\IDE\Extensions\Application**
4. Open `ssms.Application.pkgdef` with a text editor running with Administrator privileges.
5. Change the value of `DefaultProjectsLocation` to what you'd like the new default to be:

- `"DefaultProjectsLocation"="C:\My\Preferred\Save\Location"`

6. Save the file and restart SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could create new Project of type SQLServerScripts at the location you wish to store the scripts.

Then in the solution explorer just right click the queries folder to create a new script at the location you have specified.

Make sense?

Fore more detailed about Projects and solutions in SQL Server see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173803.aspx

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

An alternative may be to create an NTFS Junction Point.

Grab a copy of the [Systinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb842062), you need the junction.exe from it, and the other stuff is useful.

Run this in the command line:

```
junction.exe "c:\MyStuff" "c:\Documents and Settings\Stephen.Turner\My Documents\SQL Server Management Studio"
```

Putting in *your* My Documents path.

The directory c:\MyStuff will be created and when you browse to it you see all the filess. It's not a copy but a symbolic link, both paths refer to the sames files.

Answer (score 2):

I had no luck with any of this, my solution is to use a .bat file to create a new empty.sql file and then open it. Then in SSMS , I used 'external tools' to reun the batch. Click it and a new timed stamped .sql file is opened. I use one for each 'project'

create a .bat file

```
set fName=newQuery%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%date:~10,4%_%time:~1,1%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.sql
copy _queryBlank.sql %fName%
```

Answer (score 2):

After searching for this topic for last 3hours, i finally got the way to do this: [Changing the My Projects folder location (and other settings) in SSMS](http://visualstudiohacks.com/options/changing-the-my-projects-folder-location-and-other-settings-in-ssms/)

Comment: That's the same link as Marshall's answer from 2011 :)

Answer (score 1):

the registry changes did not work for me.  i just put a shortcut to the network folder I wanted to use in the Mgnt Studio default save path.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://csc-technicalnotes.blogspot.com/2009/09/sql-server-management-studio-default-my.html) shows one way.

But, its, registry based, solution still has a gap... When one saves a newly created query (in my SSMS 2008 setup I open it on startup), he has to click "Projects" on the left, as save dialog opens in the standard ...\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Projects.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was editing the registry and Value for DefaultFileOpenLocation

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1428394981-1396028598-1721912238-1000\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell
```

[Registry Editor screen shot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJRrE.jpg)

Comment: I searched for 18.0_IsoShell and changed everything at this level that referred to "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\" to my "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\My Documents" folder.  Why does Microsoft make this so hard to change?  I shouldn't have to run regedit to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

1. In Object Explorer, right-click on your server and click **Properties**.
2. In the left panel on that Properties page, click the **Database settings** tab.
3. In Database default locations, view the current default locations
   for new data files and new log files. To change a default location,
   enter a new default **pathname** in the Data or Log field, or click the
   browse button to find and select a pathname.

**NOTE**: After changing the default locations, you must stop and start the SQL Server service to complete the change.

Answer (score 0):

A low tech but quick solution is to simply create a shortcut in the default folder to the one where you want to save your scripts/results/etc....  It's one extra click but involves no messing with settings or the registry.

Comment: Ugh, just saw that this solution was already posted above.  sorry for the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for me was to change the folders in the registry (tested with SQL Server 2014)

Make sure to close SQL Server Management Studio before

1. Launch regedit.exe
2. Browse to Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\xx.0 (where xx is your version)
3. Change the different locations path you see in there
4. Start Management Studio and try to open a file, the default directory will be yours

However, the only problem I still have is with the Save... if I create a new Query and save, it still ends up by default under /Documents/SQL Server Management Studio but if you click on the 'SQL Management Studio' link on the left you will go directly into your directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symbolic link using mklink.

1. Delete the existing project folder (copy existing files to preferred location first):
   rmdir "C:\Users\**user**\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\SSMS Projects).
2. Create symlink to your preferred location (example a onedrive folder):
   mklink /j "C:\Users\**user**\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\SSMS Projects" "C:\Users\**user**\OneDrive - Company\SSMS Projects"

The /j options specifies a hard link that makes it appear as though the file or folder actually exists at that location. When you try to open a file in SSMS the folder should now look like this:

[Example Hard Link In SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE98Y.jpg)