# Change the default save location for SQL Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2008

As the title states, how do I do this?

I want to hit save, and have SSMS automatically direct me to a network folder..

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651535/management-studio-default-file-save-location

Answer (score 14):

This is 3 years old now, but an answer for SSMS 2012 and 2014 would be helpful, so I thought I'd add an update. Step one differs between the versions, and then the rest is the same:

**SSMS 2012**

1. Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application

**SSMS 2014**

1. Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application

**Both (continued)**

2. Open ssms.application.pkgdef with text editor(e.g. Notepad)
3. Change the value of DefaultProjectsLocation
4. "DefaultProjectsLocation"="$MyDocuments$\SQL Server Management Studio"
5. Save the file

Thanks to this source: http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php/How_to_change_the_default_query_save_location_in_SSMS/?TopicId=41425&Posts=0

Comment: As would be expected, for SSMS 2016, step one is : 
    Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application

Answer (score 3):

The correct location for 2k8 in the registry is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not editable from within the tool (for some reason), but you can adjust it from the settings file within My Documents > SQL Server Management Studio > Settings.

Look for the node "ProjectsLocation", and adjust accordingly -

`<PropertyValue name="ProjectsLocation">\\mynetworkpath</PropertyValue>`

Be sure to exit SSMS before editing this file.  This should do the trick...

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in version 2008.

Answer (score 1):

[@Kevin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825306/change-the-default-save-location-for-sql-management-studio-2008/6826406#6826406) doesn't work for SQL 2k8. One needs to change the registry:

```
key = HKEY_Current_User\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell
```

Now see where they wrote the default path... change that into any valid UNC.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me after a lot of bungling -

1. Edit registry settings as outlined in above posts (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell) - change all the paths EXCEPT MyDocumentsLocation (this is what seems to cause the settings to get reset).
2. Locate the .vssettings file from My Documents and copy to your folder + '/Settings' folder (e.g. c:\Dox\SQL Server Management Studio\Settings).
3. Start SQL studio, quit and restart.
4. Edit the .vssettings file (should be in your folder now rather than My Documents), and change the ProjectsLocation to the desired folder e.g. C:\Dox\SQL Server Management Studio\Projects
5. Start SQL studio. Opening files should now work, but save will require clicking the 'My Projects' on the left of the save dialog.